# Required value 'firstName' (JSON name 'first_name') missing at $ with retrofit moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, parsing, retrofit2, moshi

Retrofit Moshi failed to create @Body,

if I change from @put to @post error is gone, don't know the reason, any clue?

`````
data class UserProfileDto(
@JSON(name = "first_name") val firstName: String,
@JSON(name = "last_name") val lastName: String,
@JSON(name = "profile") val profile: Map<String, String>,
)

@PUT("profile")
suspend fun updateProfile(
    @Body profileUpdateRequest: UserProfileDto
): Response<UserProfileDto?>````

here is the code snippet:
`````